# How to see the domain list registered daily country or server wise?

Tags: domains

Can someone tell me about listing of domains at daily basis with country name or any other specification like server name or any others ?

I just wanted a majorly lists of domain which one daily registered and updated.

Comment: You can get a list of all registered domains, dropped domains, and newly registered domains at http://www.domaindatapro.com - also, this service provides you with daily lists of newly registered domain names and their whois contact information: http://www.easywhoispro.com

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single place where you can check that because there are different types and regions for domains, which have their own registrars. But this might help out with what you want:

http://www.dailychanges.com/

You can see domain data for each nameserver. For example clicking on HOSTGATOR.COM will take you to a page where you can see every new domain, every transfer, every deleted domain HOSTGATOR has.

Comment: Thanks for your help boss. are you tell me any other website like www.dailychanges.com where we find the above information.

Comment: None come to mind. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Each registry makes a list of newly registered domain names available.  There are lots of registeries and you would have to apply to each of them for this data.

There are also brokers that have done this work and make the data available for a fee.

[This question on stackoverflow has answers for both approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/possible-to-download-entire-whois-database-list-of-registered-domains).